# ¿Cual es el problema para que .length no funcione?

Tags: java

Estoy empezando con Java y no se cual es el problema en el Array de este código, para que en el bucle FOR no pueda usar .length para usar la longitud del Array.

```
import java.util.*;
public class lab_eje8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Double>notas = new ArrayList<Double>();
        double nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, contador;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresar notas: ");
        nota1 = sc.nextDouble();
        notas.add(nota1);
        nota2 = sc.nextDouble();
        notas.add(nota2);
        nota3 = sc.nextDouble();
        notas.add(nota3);
        nota4 = sc.nextDouble();
        notas.add(nota4);
        contador = 0;
        
        for (double i = 0; i < notas.length;i++){
            if (i > contador) {
                contador = notas[i];
            }
            else {
                notas.remove(i);
            }
            }
        double suma = 0
        for (double x = 0; x < notas.length; x++) {
            suma += notas.length;               
        }
        double promedio = suma/notas.length;
        System.out.println(promedio);
        
        System.out.println(notas);
        sc.close();        
    }
}
```

Esta mal declarado el Array o cual es el problema.
Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Revisa siempre la documentación de las clases que estés usando. El método para determinar el tamaño de los objetos `ArrayList` es [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()), no existe propiedad `length` para este objeto.

Comment: Al margen que en un ``ArrayList`` se usa ``size()`` en lugar de ``length``, revisa bien la lógica de tu programa porque no tiene sentido lo que quieres realizar en el primer y segundo bucle ``for``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa siempre la documentación de las clases que estés usando. El método para determinar el tamaño de los objetos `ArrayList` es [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()), no existe propiedad `length` para este objeto.

Por tanto, para determinar el tamaño de tu objeto puedes hacer algo así:

```
    for (double i = 0; i < notas.size();i++){
        // ...


    for (double x = 0; x < notas.size(); x++) {
        // ...
```

Si quieres evaluar otros métodos de lectura, puedes consultar [este artículo](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-loop-arraylist-in-java/).

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un ejemplo de la forma correcta de hacerlo utilizando un array simple, del que tendremos que dar el límite del mismo, y de un arrayList

A destacar el error de utilizar variables doubles en los bucles, no tiene sentido hacerlo, pues lo que haces es consumir más memoria y hacerlo más lento.

Para los contadores al igual que para los bucles, también usaremos variables enteras.

Lo que no acabé de adivinar es el sentido del if dentro del bucle, no logro entender que era lo que pretendías con el mismo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declaramos las variables doubles     
    double nota, suma = 0;
    //instalaciamos la clase scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //pedimos el número de notas
    System.out.println("Ingresar el nº de notas: ");
    //almacenmos ese número de notas en la variable nNotas
    int nNotas = sc.nextInt();
    //declaramos el array de notas con el límite del número de notas
    double[] notas = new double[nNotas];
    
    //bucle que recorre el array
    for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){
        //pedimos la nota número iteración del array más 1
        System.out.println("Ingresar la nota " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        //almacenamos la nota introducida en la posición del array
        notas[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        //vamos acumulando el valor de las notas en la viable suma
        suma += notas[i];
    }
    //calculamos el promedio diviendo la suma de las notas entre el total de notas
    double promedio = suma / notas.length;
    //sacamos las notas por consola
    System.out.println("Las notas del alumno ");
    //bucle que recorre el array menos una posición
    for (int i = 0; i < notas.length - 1; i++){
        //imprimimos la nota en la posición del array más una coma
        System.out.print(notas[i] + ", ");
    }
    //imprimimos la última posición dl array sin coma
    System.out.println(notas[notas.length - 1]);
    
    //formateamos la salida a dos decimales
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    //imprimimos el resultado con el formateo de dos decimales del promedio
    System.out.println("La nota media del total de notas es de: " + df.format(promedio));       
    
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
    
    //utilzando arrayList, no hace falta declarar el límete del mismo
    ArrayList<Double>notasII = new ArrayList<Double>();      
    //declaramos las variables doubles
    double notaII = 0, sumaII = 0;
    //declaramos un contador entero
    int contador = 0;
    
    //mientras no se introduzca un 11, nos irá pidiendo una nota
    while (notaII != 11){
        //pedimos la nota
        System.out.println("Ingresar la nota " + (contador + 1) + ": (11 Sale)");
        //almacenamos la nota en la variable
        notaII = sc.nextDouble();
        //para no contabilizar la nota 11 de salida, vilidamos que no sea esa nota para realizar las operaciones
        if (notaII != 11){
            //guardamos esa nota en el aarayList
            notasII.add(notaII);
            //acumulamos la suma de las notas en la variable
            //llegamos al valor del arrayList por medio del .get() indicando el lugar que ocupa
            sumaII += notasII.get(contador);
            //aumentamos el contador
            contador ++;
        }
    }
    //calculamos el promedio dividiendo la suma entre el total de notas
    double promedioII = sumaII / notasII.size();
    //mostramos el número de totas introducido
    System.out.println("Se han introducido " + notasII.size() + " notas");
    //mostramos las notas
    System.out.println("Las notas son ");
    //bucle que recorre el arrayList
    for (int i = 0; i < notasII.size() - 1; i++){
        //obtenemos la nota del arrayList por medio del .get y el lugar que ocupa más una coma
        System.out.print(notasII.get(i) + ", ");
    }
    //mostramos el último valor del arrayList
    System.out.println(notasII.get(notasII.size() - 1));
    //formateamos la salida del resultado
    DecimalFormat dfII = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    //mostramos el resultado formateado a dos decimales
    System.out.println("La nota media del total de notas es de: " + dfII.format(promedioII));
    //cerramos la calse escaner
    sc.close();        
}
```